# Normal map is looking weird and showing bumps that are not sculpted in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting, normal-map, bump, brushes, sculpt-mode

I don't know if anyone can notice at the middle of the normal map, there are strange pumps that I had not sculpted, but clearly showing here, even when I apply my normal map to the low poly mesh, it shows bumps, I couldn't know what's going on here. I tried to reconstruct the low poly mesh, moving vertices away from each other. but the result is the same. my mirror is applied.
I couldn't find such case on youtube or other.

Comment: I think you forgot to add an image, right?

Comment: Do you mean image texture?  I did

Comment: I just found what was going on, the Extrusion was too high, 0.6, so it is baking lots of details, I think this includes the slight variations or errors found with the basic mesh geometry, like the close vertices, lines, and faces. anyway, I tried to lower it by 0.02 to 0.03 and this solved the problem properly.

Comment: No, I meant that you forgot to **add a screenshot to your question**. You wrote: *"I don't know if anyone can notice at the middle of the normal map, there are strange pumps that I had not sculpted, ..."* - No, we can't notice the strange bumps because we have no idea what you sculpted nor what bumps you are talking about ;-)